Understanding Python Reference Documentation
In the library reference for list comprehensions, the BNF syntax for "expression_list" provides a link to "expression" Which one would assume would go on to say that you can use any valid Python 3 expression in your list comprehension, however it instead takes you to a section called "Conditional expressions"
This seems to imply this is the only expression supported, as nothing else is mentioned. However the data structures guide in the tutorial is much more clear:

A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression
followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses.


To include all possible operators and other things of the expression grammar in the right order and priority, it begins at the if-expression (lowest priority), goes through comparison, arithmetic operators up to the primaries. If you look closely, you will see that the conditional_expression doesn't require an if-else but can be just an or_test. It is similar for the other grammar rules on the way to the top (or bottom, depends on how you look at it).

@MichaelButscher Thanks for replying. Reading the section about "or_test" doesn't seem to give me any more information though. It seems to relate to booleans, true or false. What about expressions that evaluate to a string, number etc?
I can't seem to find anywhere in the docs (Other than the Tutorial) that just says "List comprehensions always start with an expression. An expression is something that evaluates to a value" or words to that effect, as I would expect.

The type of the value the expression evaluates to is not part of the grammar. It works independently of that, e.g. "Test" + 1 is syntactically correct but raises a TypeError. By the way: The and and or operators don't necessarily return bools but always one of their two operands. If you look at the grammar, or_test can be just an and_test which can be just a not_test. This goes on: not_test -> comparison -> or_expr -> xor_expr -> and_expr -> ...

Note, too, that the grammar snippets found in the library reference for various constructs are often out of date with the  official grammar. At a high level, you'll work your way through disjunctions, conjunctions, inversions, bitwise expressions, and shift expressions before you finally reach sums (addition and subtraction), terms (multiplication and division), factors, powers, primaries, and atoms. An atom, finally, is what can be a number, string, Boolean constant, etc.
